# Stack View Wrap Elements

Tags: swift, autolayout, uistackview

My overall container is a vertical stack view.

Inside of it, I want to have two Buttons with dynamically generated content.

For larger devices where both button text's fit inside the screen dimensions, I want the two buttons to be side-by-side.

On smaller devices, I want the second button to auto-wrap to a second line, since both texts wouldn't fit, rather than truncating the text of one of the two.

How would you go about accomplishing something like this?

Answer (score 1):

There isn’t any code to add to but what I would do is put the two buttons into a stack view.

Then use some logic in your view or view controller that does something along the lines of...

```
buttonStackView.axis = screenWidth < threshold ? .vertical : .horizontal
```

Set the threshold value to whatever width you want for the switch to happen.

This assumes that you mean small like iPhone 5 and large like iPhone X.

For iPhone vs iPad you can use the size class of the screen instead of a point size.